# Sending serial data with python gives an error on windows but not on linux

Tags: python, serial-port

I'm using python to send data out to my arduino and for some reason under windows it's giving me an error.
Below is my code.

```
import serial 

ser = serial.Serial("COM3")

ser.write('1')
```

Here is the error.

> ```
>   File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py",
> ```
>
> line 255, in write
>           raise SerialException("WriteFile failed
>   (%s)" % ctypes.WinError())
>       serial.serialutil.SerialException: WriteFile failed ([Error 9] The handle
>   is invalid.)

Any idea why it's giving me this?

Comment: Use the 101010 button for proper code formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure `COM3` is a valid serial port on your Windows box? Can you open it with `HyperTerminal` and send stuff to it?

If it is, another thing to try is to replace it with the fully qualified name, for example:

```
port = "\\\\.\\COM3"
ser = serial.Serial(port, 38400)
```

Comment: Yet another thing to do is replace `"COM3"` with the literal int `2`.